# C++ classes, segmentation fault when calling member function

Tags: c++, class, segmentation-fault

I am now learning C++ and have been experimenting with classes just to get my head around how they work. I have only programmed classes in Java before now.

In my code I have a class definition and a driver to test. In comments I have mention what works and what doesn't.  I really want to know why instantiating objects one way works but in other ways I get errors. Is it the compiler, the make file, or the class code? Constructor/default constructor? When I compare my code to others like a textbook, I can't see where I've gone wrong.

Using: code::blocks 10.5 on Linux Mint 13.

Header file:

```
#ifndef ENEMY_H
#define ENEMY_H
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Enemy
{
public:
    Enemy();
    Enemy(int, int, string); 
    ~Enemy();

    string display();

    // setter and getters:
    int getHP();
    void setHP(int);
    int getX();
    void setX(int);
    int getY();
    void setY(int);
    string getName();
    void setName(string);

private:
    int hitpoints;
    int x_pos;
    int y_pos;
    string name;
};
#endif // ENEMY_H
```

member function defifnitions:

```
#include "Enemy.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


// default ctor 
Enemy::Enemy()
{
    cout << "Creating enemy with default ctor.\n";
}

//ctor
Enemy::Enemy(int x, int y, string str)
{
    cout << "Creating object with  name: " << str << endl;
    setX(x);
    setY(y);
    setHP(100);
    setName(str);
}

//dtor
Enemy::~Enemy()
{
    cout << "destroying Enemy: " << name << endl;
}

string Enemy::display()
{
    cout<<name<<" -  x: "<<x_pos<<", y: "<<y_pos<<", HP: "<<hitpoints<<endl;
}

int Enemy::getHP(){
    return hitpoints;
}
void Enemy::setHP(int hp){
   hitpoints = hp;
}
int Enemy::getX(){
    return x_pos;
}
void Enemy::setX(int x){
    x_pos = x;
}
int Enemy::getY(){
    return y_pos;
}
void Enemy::setY(int y){
    y_pos = y;
}
string Enemy::getName(){
    return name;
}
void Enemy::setName(string objectName){
    name = objectName;
}
// end of function definitions
```

Driver:

```
#include "Enemy.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Program started.\n" << endl;

    // initialise a few Enemy objects
    Enemy E1(1, 1, "E1");
    Enemy E2(2, -4, "E2");
    Enemy E3;
    Enemy E4;
    Enemy *E5 = new Enemy(4, 5, "E5");


    E1.display(); // <- success!
    E2.display(); // <- success!
    E3.display(); // <- segmentation fault at run time
    E4.display(); // <- segmentation fault at run time
    E5.display(); // <- compile time error "request for member
                  //    'display'" in 'E5'. which is of
                  //    non-class type 'enemy'

    cout << "end of program.\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read the [faq]; you'll get a badge (c:

Comment: @PeterWood Is it a special invisible badge that only the super trusted can see?

Comment: @StarPilot The [Analytical](http://stackoverflow.com/badges/1306/analytical) badge is awarded if you visit every section of the [faq].

Answer (score 5):

When you say `Enemy E3;`, you call the default constructor. It takes care of default-initializing your data members. While this means that your `std::string` member is initialized to an empty string, it also means that your other members are left uninitialized (just like how doing `int i; std::cout << i;` is bad). This causes undefined behaviour when you read the value in your output statement, which means anything can happen. It chose to crash.

As for `E5`, it's a pointer. You need to dereference it to get the object you can call a member with:

```
(*E5).display();
```

There's also a shortcut to do this:

```
E5->display();
```

As jrok points out, you also don't return anything from `display`, even though it should return a `std::string`. This is undefined behaviour for every function besides `main`, which will return 0 upon reaching the closing brace.

As a side note, you have a memory leak because you did not `delete E5;`. In this case, it's almost certain that the OS will take care of releasing that memory, but put that into a loop and you'll see your memory rise and rise.

If you need a single object to be dynamically allocated, use a smart pointer:

```
std::unique_ptr<Enemy> E5(new Enemy(4, 5, "E5"));
```

In C++14, we're also getting `std::make_unique`, thankfully, eliminating the need for `new`.

Comment: But if this is compiled in debug, shouldn't the primitives be assigned 0? Why is E3 causing the segfault? Not critiquing your answer, I agree with everything you said but not sure about E3, unless it's being compiled in release.

Comment: @Ryan, Not necessarily, though I know that for example, MSVC will fill uninitialized memory with a noticeable pattern. Compilers do warn for using uninitialized variables. It could also be the undefined behaviour from the missing return statement.

Comment: duh! I should have initialised the data members in my default constructor. For some reason I thought the default constructor would have automatically initalised those to 0, 0, NULL. But that would only be if I had not make my own default ctor and the compiler provided one, right?

Thanks for the note on E5. I also should have known to use '->' instead of '.' for a pointer. And I'll try to remember to delete after using 'new'.

Thanks guys.

Comment: @MatthewZeitgeistBishop, A compiler-generated default constructor would not initialize them either. If left uninitialized, data members are default-initialized. For built-in types like `int`, this means it is left uninitialized, which extends to certain POD classes as well. For things like `std::string`, your class, etc, the default constructor is called.

Answer (score 5):

What's causing a segfault is the fact that you're flowing off the edge of a function that's supposed to return a `string` (which is undefined behavior):

```
string Enemy::display()
//^^^^ you're supposed to return a string
{
    cout<<name<<" -  x: "<<x_pos<<", y: "<<y_pos<<", HP: "<<hitpoints<<endl;
    // no return statement
}
```

The rest is in @chris' answer.

Comment: Oh hey, I didn't notice that. I don't mind you adding your explanation of the others. It's always good to have it explained different ways. @OP, turn on your compiler warnings, as it will definitely tell you about this.

Comment: @chris No need to, you explained well.

Answer (score 0):

On the subject of E3 and E4 seg faulting on display, you are trying to print variables that have not been initialized yet.  And your E5 is a pointer, which you should probably dereference to gain access to the method.

Answer (score 0):

First, don't put a using namespace declaration in your header file.  Use std::string there and put the namespace declaration in your .cpp.

Second, give your integers default values in the default constructor (0 is reasonable.  Strings are automatically initialized to empty strings, so you don't have to do anything with those unless you need to.

```
Enemy::Enemy()
{
  x_pos = 0;
  y_pos = 0;
  ...;
}
```

Finally, E5 is a pointer to Enemy (a location in memory), which means you have to use the arrow operator (->) instead of . to access it's methods.